# R: Keep Upper Case with TermDocumentMatrix

Tags: r, uppercase, lowercase

I want to create a wordcloud with the `wordcloud` package. My problem is that I want to keep the upper case at the beginning of the words but all letters are automatically transformed to lower cases.

As far as I see, this happens when I use the `TermDocumentMatrix` function. Is there a possibility to prevent the function from transforming all letters to lower cases?

Comment: What did you try? Do you have a reproducible example? What is the `TermDocumentMatrix` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent `TermDocumentMatrix` from converting everything to lower case, by specifying `tolower=FALSE` in your control list.   Since you do not provide any data, I will illustrate with the sample data provided in the tm package.

```
library(wordcloud)
library(tm)
data(crude)

tdm = TermDocumentMatrix(crude, 
    control=list(removePunctuation=T, tolower=F, stopwords=T))
WordFreq = slam::row_sums(tdm[tdm$dimnames$Terms, ])
FrequentWords = tail(sort(WordFreq), 20)
wordcloud(names(FrequentWords), FrequentWords)
```

[image: Word Cloud]